# WPF Error in routine

Tags: c#, wpf

I had this subroutine code (See below) working just fine until an hour ago while testing.

NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => TestResults); triggers the error:

"Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type"

I have googled around, and most solutions suggest adding "using System.Linq". I have done this as well as "using System.Data.Entity".  Both of these are greyed out in Visual Studio suggesting that they are not used, and the error still persists.

I'm new to using WPF linked to subroutines, so I'm not entirely sure what it is doing, but like I said its been working fine, and I have another similar program where there is no error.  Both have the same references and usings, and my other program doesn't even have "using System.Linq"

I'm sure its something stupid I'm missing.  Thanks

```
  public string TestResults
    {
        get { return _testResults; }

        set
        {
            _testResults = value; 
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => TestResults);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Obviously `NotifyOfPropertyChange` takes a string instead of a lambda expression (notice the `() => `)?). What are you supposed to pass as the value? The name of the changed property?

Comment: try adding System.Linq.Expressions

Comment: As far as I know, I pass it like it is in the code.  As I said, it was working fine.  I've also added System.Linq.Expressions and the error changes to tell me that need to add System.Linq.Expressions.Expressions. Which makes no sense.

Comment: can you post the `NotifyOfPropertyChange` method?

Comment: If I click Go To Definiton, I get this: public virtual void NotifyOfPropertyChange(string propertyName = null);

Comment: When you go to definition, do you get the `PropertyChangedBase` class located in assembly `Caliburn.Micro.dll`? Try reinstall the NuGet...

Comment: Yes, its definitely located in Caliburn.Micro.dll.  I've removed and reinstalled the caliburn package from nuget.  Something got blitzed in my project. I'm going to recreating it from scratch and copy paste my classes into it.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you implement the interface INotifyPropertyChanged and should fire the PropertyChanged event by providing the name of the property. So I guess you can just call NotifyOfPropertyChange("TestResults") and it will work.

Comment: I tried this, and I get an error telling me to add a reference to System.Linq.Expressions, but I already have a using for that, and its not available to add as a reference.